# Mostar datos en JSON (filtro en listas con diccionarios)

Tags: python, json, lista, diccionarios

quiero obtener una lista solo con el nombre y el año a partir de un json. No consigo filtrar la información de una forma que no sea la siguiente, pero me parece poco correcta.

```
import json
import requests
url='https://opendata-ajuntament.barcelona.cat/data/api/action/datastore_search? 
resource_id=e1b5dd1f-a88e-43eb-86d1-d3880d9a6718&q={"Ordre":"1"}'
response=requests.get(url)
data=response.json()
response
listado=data['result']['records']
print("Año Nombre")
for t in listado:
     print(t['Any'],t['Nom'])
```

Con esto consigo solo consigo visualizarlo, me gustaría almacenarlo en una lista y luego hacer un conteo sobre ella (ordenándolos por los nombres que más se repiten).

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado, espero haber sido claro.

pd. También traté de conseguir: (Año, Nombre de mujer ,nombre de hombre) pero ya desistí. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`data` es un diccionario, con diccionarios anidados, la forma en la que obtienes las claves es correcta. La idea es la misma que usa para imprimir las claves, solo de debes agregarlas a una lista en vez de imprimir.

Si quieres una lista de listas, puedes hacer algo como:

```
import json
import requests


url='https://opendata-ajuntament.barcelona.cat/data/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=e1b5dd1f-a88e-43eb-86d1-d3880d9a6718&q={"Ordre":"1"}'

response=requests.get(url)
data=response.json()
data_list = [[record["Nom"], record["Any"], record["Sexe"]]
             for record in data["result"]["records"]
             ]
```

> ```
> >>> data_list
>
> [['LAURA', '1996', 'Dona'],
>  ['MARIA', '1997', 'Dona'],
>  ['MARIA', '1998', 'Dona'],
>  ...,
>  ['MARC', '2018', 'Home']]
> ```

Aunque quizás sea mas legible y más fácil de trabajar con ellos después, usar un alista de diccionarios y no una lista de listas:

```
import json
import requests


url='https://opendata-ajuntament.barcelona.cat/data/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=e1b5dd1f-a88e-43eb-86d1-d3880d9a6718&q={"Ordre":"1"}'
response=requests.get(url)
data=response.json()
data_dict = [{"nombre": record["Nom"],
              "año": record["Any"],
              "sexo": record["Sexe"]}
             for record in data["result"]["records"]
             ]
```

> ```
> >>> data_dict
> [{'nombre': 'LAURA', 'año': '1996', 'sexo': 'Dona'},
>  {'nombre': 'MARIA', 'año': '1997', 'sexo': 'Dona'},
>  {'nombre': 'LUCIA', 'año': '2007', 'sexo': 'Dona'},
>  {'nombre': 'MARC', 'año': '2003', 'sexo': 'Home'}, 
>  ...]
> ```

---

Si quieres ordenar la lista de mayor  menor en función de los nombres más comunes, puedes usar `collections.Counter` para contarlos y usarlo junto al argumento `key` de `list.sort()`/`sorted()`.

```
import collections

counter = collections.Counter(record[0] for record in data_list)
data_list.sort(key=lambda record: counter[record[0]], reverse=True)
```

Si quieres solo entradas únicas ordenadas de mayor a menor en funcíon de lo comunes que son los nombres, genera un alista de tuplas que son hashables y usa `collections.Counter` directamente:

Comment: ¿Y como sería agregar a una lista el resultado en vez de imprimir? Sé que es de lo más sencillo pero no lo consigo. Aprovecho para agradecer tu respuesta!

Comment: Hola uland, en mis ejemplos `data_list` en el primero es una lista de listas con los datos y en el segundo `data_dict` una lista de diccionarios. Puedes iterar sobre ellos, ordenarlos o hacer lo que necesites.

Comment: Entendía lo que me explicabas pero no lo había estudiado con detenimiento, gracias.Abusando de tu conocimiento, llevo desde tú respuesta intentando ordenar el resultado por el número de veces que se repite cada nombre de mayor a menor y no hay manera...gracias

Comment: @uland mira la edición de la respuesta, al final a ver si es lo que buscas.